# How to pass a Parameter to a OpenQuery in SSIS OLE DB Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, bids

How do you pass a parameter to an Openquery SQL Statement in a OLE DB Source in SSIS?

Example: 
   Standard SQL command:  SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE PERSONID = ?

OpenQuery command does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(CRMDB
            , 'SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PUBLIC.CUSTOMERS WHERE PERSONID = ''?'' ')
```

More Detail if needed:

1. The SSIS package will use a ForEach loop to query a Linked Server using OpenQuery, thus the need for passing it a parameter.
2. Must use a linked server and must use OpenQuery.
3. Table is too large to import into a local table to query from.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Using SQL SERVER 2008 with Visual Studio 2008 BIDS

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: added to main detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it used much, but [EXECUTE...AT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) is perfect if you're faced with linked server queries.

```
DECLARE @PersonId INTEGER = <value>;
EXECUTE ('SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PUBLIC.CUSTOMERS WHERE PERSONID = ?',
         @PersonId) AT CRMDB;
```

This requires `RPC` and `RPC Out` to be enabled for the linked server.

[image: Linked server properties]

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. Executing in SQL Enterprise Manager gives CRMDB RPC not available. When I use Visual Studio 2008 BIDS to add this in, it does not recognize the PersonID = ? as a place for a parameter, gives error "No Parameters Available". Thanks for the try.

Comment: @ConsultingMechanic RPC has to be enabled for the linked server.

Comment: RPC enabled but Visual Studio 2008 BIDS is not recognizing the ? as parameters.
Running the query above in Enterprise Manager gives error could not execute statement on remote server CRMDB.

Comment: Confirm that it works in SSMS before you go any further with SSIS. If the OLEDB source task isn't working for your situation, try the OLE DB Command task as a source. If that doesn't work, use a script task to the query and execute against the source. Or better yet, query the source directly. Linked servers aren't built for moving large amounts of data around...SSIS is.

Comment: If I run an SSIS package that does not have a parameter then everything works correctly going through the linked server. 
Query used:
    <code>
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CRMDB, 'SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PUBLIC.CUSTOMERS WHERE AddDate >= ''1/1/2014'' ')
</code>
This got me the full list of customers and able to perform rest of extraction. Just need to get the same query to accept a parameter.

BTW thanks for the questions and help so far.